# Mean absolute difference of squared norms

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let $\Lambda$ be a diagonal positive semidefinite $n\times n$ matrix, and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ scalar vector.
Let $P$ be $k\times n$ matrix with standard normal entries.

Let $X:=\Lambda P^TPx/k$ (and so $E[X]=\Lambda x$).

Consider $E[\vert \|X\|^2_2-\|E[X]\|^2_2 \vert]$, i.e. the mean absolute difference of squared norms.

I would like to find out the order of this expression w.r.t. $k$ and have a tight upper bound.

Jensen's inequality gives the lower bound $E[ \|X\|^2_2] -\|E[X]\|^2_2$ (which I can compute and is of order $\operatorname{Tr}(\Lambda^2)\|x\|^2_2/k$). Based on numerics, this lower bound seems very tight, so I'm hoping that a small constant factor of the lower bound $E_P[ \|\Lambda P^TPx/k\|^2_2] -\|\Lambda x\|^2_2$ might be an upper bound, but don't have a proof. Ideas much appreciated.